# Translation of workaround (as a temporary solution to bypass a problem)

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, anglicismes

Does solution de contournement translate *workaround* in the sense of:

> A means of overcoming some obstacle, especially an obstacle consisting of laws, regulations, or constraints

?

Can we use workaround in French as it is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J'entends et utilise couramment ***workaround*** en français, mais uniquement dans un contexte technique (informatique).

Il s'agit alors d'une méthode qui permet de débloquer temporairement et rapidement une situation avant de s'attaquer à l'origine de celle-ci (la *root cause*) pour fournir à terme une solution pérenne.

« **Solution de contournement** » est aussi utilisé dans ce cas et correspond bien à cette définition.

« **Palliatif** » proposé ailleurs rend aussi très bien l'idée de ne pas s'attaquer à la cause profonde mais seulement aux symptômes, mais s'entend plus dans un contexte médical.

« Solution de rechange » et « solution de remplacement » ne correspondent pas à l'usage que je connais de *workaround*. Il s'agit plutôt d'un « plan B », c'est à dire un deuxième choix qui apporte une solution faite pour durer.

Je n'utiliserai pas en revanche *workaround* quand il s'agit de lois ou de règles. Ce sera plutôt  « détournement » ou « contournement » des règles, d'une « exploitation de leurs failles ».

Answer (score 4):

La *Banque de dépannage linguistique* propose [**solution de rechange**](http://www.gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8366441), de laquelle on indique que :

> Contrairement à une réparation, la solution de rechange n'est que temporaire et ne règle pas le problème.

Il arrive bien sûr parfois que les solutions de rechange qui visent à se plier à des lois ou à faire face à des contraintes plus sévères qu’à l’ordinaire voient leur statut temporaire s’éterniser. On parlerait mieux alors d’une **méthode de travail adaptée aux conditions** pour un environnement difficile (par exemple le long d’une falaise prompte aux éboulements), ou simplement d’une **nouvelle méthode de travail** si des lois en vigueur empêchent les méthodes habituelles.

L’*Académie française*, elle, propose [**solution de remplacement**](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/solutions-alternatives).

Pour une traduction en un seul mot, on pourra penser au [**palliatif**](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/palliatif) ou à l’[**expédient**](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/exp%C3%A9dient)

Answer (score 2):

Je vois bien que plusieurs ressources du net proposent :

*solution de contournement*

Un peu d'originalité s'impose donc et, devant le silence (provisoire) de FranceTerme, je voterai pour ma part et sans détour pour la substantivisation du verbe *circonvenir* c'est donc à dire : Un ***circonvenant***.

Ce n'est évidemment pas une *bonne traduction* mais... on observera que cette solution de contournement n'est que très souvent un... ***pis-aller*** De là à jouer la transitivité... ;-)

Comment: Personne n'utilise "circonvenant". La question demande une façon si possible idiomatique de le dire, pas un mot du fond du dictionnaire dont la plupart des natifs connaissent pas le sens.

Comment: « Circonvenant » me fait plus penser à une personne. Je ne vois pas beaucoup d'exemples de participes présents qui désignent autre chose qu'une entité animée. À vrai dire, je n'en ai pour l'instant trouvé aucun.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Tu m'attendais au... *tournant* ?

Comment: Ah, il en existe donc :-)

Answer (score 1):

Il y a le terme "solution de rechange" puis le terme "palliatif" trouvé plus soutenu.

Cependant ces termes semblent être appliqués à des cas particulier de traduction du terme « workaround », pas nécessairement convenable dans le domaine de la science.

On trouve souvent les termes « contournement  et « solution de contournement . Il semble que dans un contexte scientifique/technologique il soit une bonne idée de s'en tenir à ces termes et même de préserver le terme « solution » comme les solutions de contournement s'avèrent être des solutions à part entière.

Apparemment personne n'utilise "workaround" comme on ne le trouve pas tout au moins dans certain des dictionnaires « avancés » tels que le reverso ; cependant, il existe possiblement plusieurs poches d'usage dont l'une est attesté par @jlliagre comme étant assez importante ; il considèrerait le terme comme au moins du jargon, mais là est encore un problème : est-ce que tous les termes étrangers au tout début de leur introduction dans le langage doivent être appelés du jargon ? Peut être devrait-on dire que le terme est à l'essai.

Comment: Si, moi ! (*et mes potes* comme dirait l'autre...)

Comment: If you feel that you and  your acolytes have to be a law unto yourselves, now, it's a different story!

Comment: I know thousands of native French people who routinely use *workaround* in otherwise plain French sentences so this word might at least be called *jargon*.

Comment: J'ai utilisé *jargon* car ce mot n'est aujourd'hui utilisé que par une population bien définie : [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jargon) : *Code linguistique particulier à un groupe socio-culturel ou professionnel, à une activité, se caractérisant par un lexique spécialisé, qui peut être incompréhensible ou difficilement compréhensible pour les non initiés*

Answer (score 1):

As a noun, "*contournement*" doesn't really fit, but if you can rephrase your sentence, "contourner le problème" is used a lot.

> "I used a workaround" = "J'ai contourné le problème"

I'm not a big fan of "*solution de rechange*", it might imply that you already had a backup solution. It's closer to a "plan B" than to a workaround.

And *workaround* is never used as is in French, unlike *plug-in* or *upload* for example.

Comment: Pas d'accord, *workaround* est parfois utilisé (dans le milieu professionnel informatique, pas en français général)